# how do i print name key field inside a circle using d3.js

Tags: jquery, json, d3.js

I am very new to D3 so basically going through bunch of examples and problems to try it out. I have a json which looks like this

and the d3 stuff looks like this.

```
<div id="body">
      <div id="chart"></div>
    </div>
 var inNodes = getNodes();

var w = 600,
    h = 400,
    z = d3.scale.category20c();

var force = d3.layout.force()
         .linkDistance(100)
        .size([w, h])
        .charge(-430);

var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

svg.append("svg:rect")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

  var nodes = flatten(inNodes),
      links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);

  force
      .nodes(nodes)
      .links(links)
      .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll("line")
      .data(links)
    .enter().insert("svg:line")
      .style("stroke", "#999")
      .style("stroke-width", "1px");

  var node = svg.selectAll("circle.node")
      .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("svg:circle")
      .attr("r", function(d){return d.size*2})
      .style("fill", function(d) { return z(d.parent && d.parent.name); })
      .style("stroke", "#000")
      .call(force.drag);  

  force.on("tick", function(e) {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  });


function flatten(root) {
  var nodes = [];
  function recurse(node, depth) {
    if (node.children) {
      node.children.forEach(function(child) {
        child.parent = node;
        recurse(child, depth + 1);
      });
    }
    node.depth = depth;
    nodes.push(node);
  }
  recurse(root, 1);
  return nodes;
}
```

I am getting a bit lost in the syntax here. So need some help with this. I am trying to print the name of each node inside the node.

```
function getNodes() {

var inNodes = {
    "name": "APP",
    "children": [
        {
        "name": "API 1",
        "size": 10
        },
        {
        "name": "API 2",
        "size": 10
        },
        {
        "name": "API 3",
        "size": 10,
        }
    ],
    "size":20
};

return inNodes;
}
```

I looked into whole bunch of examples but not really understanding how things are happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: http://tributary.io/inlet/5809527

You need to `append` an svg `text` element for each data point. Then, in the `tick()` function, you set the `"dx"` (and `"dy"`) attribute of the text to be the same as the `"cx"` (and `"cy"`) attribute of the circle.